# hdfs text with 3rd party writable

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, writable

I have generated an hdfs sequence file and it uses a 3rd party library's `Writable`, so when I try to show the text of the file by running `hadoop fs -text /some/file/path`, I get an error message saying:

> text: java.io.IOException: WriableName can't load class: org.example.AnotherWritable

In this case, how do I go about using the `-text` command so it can resolve `AnotherWritable`

Comment: Do you have to use the `-text` command for what you're trying to achieve? If you're merely trying to show the contents of the file is `-cat` not sufficient?

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl The file is a binary sequence file, running -cat just gives me binary output.